# In release build getting MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget, webp

Our Xamarin.iOS release build is failing with MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol. This error started happening recently and is likely due to a nuget package somewhere but the funny thing is none of those APIs look familiar at all. I've tried investigating the source but can't find where they're getting included.

I've tried. 
1. Downgrading Xamarin forms from latest version to the last point version 2.5xxxx
2. Removing all nuget packages added since our last update in July.
3. Adding --registrar:static 
4. Adding -gcc_flags -dead_strip which reduce the errors but still results in this error
_*__2018-08-24T22:01:20.5791820Z clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/projectName.Forms.iOS.csproj]
2018-08-24T22:01:20.5920220Z error MT5209 : Native linking error : reference to symbol (which has not been assigned an address) _WebPInitYUV444Converters in '_CustomSetup' from /Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/WebP.a(libwebpdecode_la-io_dec.o) for architecture armv7 [/Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/projectName.Forms.iOS.csproj]
2018-08-24T22:01:20.6050340Z MTOUCH : error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -dead_strip [/Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/projectName.Forms.iOS.csproj]
2018-08-24T22:01:20.6130420Z MTOUCH : error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/projectName.Forms.iOS.csproj]
2018-08-24T22:01:20.6148240Z 
2018-08-24T22:01:20.6180880Z 60 Warning(s)
2018-08-24T22:01:20.6215590Z 4 Error(s)*

various --linkskip options to suspect nuget dlls .
How do I get the full error? Can i by pass these ? Here's the a portion of the log file, any help/pointers is greatly appreciated.

*2018-08-29T07:57:46.1674730Z duplicate symbol _WebPMultRows in:
2018-08-29T07:57:46.1761750Z /Users/vsts/agent/2.138.6/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/obj/iPhone/Staging/mtouch-cache/WebP.a(libwebpdspdecode_la-alpha_processing.o)
2018-08-29T07:57:46.1944120Z /Users/vsts/agent/2.138.6/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/obj/iPhone/Staging/mtouch-cache/liblibwebp.a(alpha_processing.o)
2018-08-29T07:57:46.2117500Z duplicate symbol _WebPMultARGBRows in:
2018-08-29T07:57:46.2265350Z /Users/vsts/agent/2.138.6/work/1/s/Client/projectName.Client.Forms/iOS/obj/iPhone/Staging/mtouch-cache/WebP.a(libwebpdspdecode_la-alpha_processing.o)*

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for this error:

- The same native library is included twice.
- Two distinct native libraries happen to define the same symbols.
- A native library is not correctly built, and contains the same symbol
  more than once. You can confirm this by using the following set of
  commands from a terminal (replace i386 with x86_64/armv7/armv7s/arm64
  according to which architecture you're building for):

  for more information you can access link [error-messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5xxx-gcc-and-toolchain-error-messages)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me as I mentioned. I have also tried building on my PC, Mac and even in AppCenter builds all with the same error, trying various combinations of mtouch arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the following to mtouch arguments in all configurations, specifically for release|iphone (simulator was working prior)

--registrar:static  -gcc_flags "-framework libSkipSharp -dead_strip"

This link was instrumental  including a lot trial and error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5xxx-gcc-and-toolchain-error-messages